# Uploaded file directory in Symfony 2.8

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, upload

I just made a file upload form in my project, thanks to Symfony documentation.
My project is in version 2.8.

In MySQL, I have my Media table with File for emplacement. I thought Symfony created a upload directory, but the link looks like this:

Media

```
+---------+----+--------------+----------------+
| Libelle | ID | Cat_Media_ID | file           |
+---------+----+--------------+----------------+
| test    |  1 |            1 | /tmp/phpY0oLd6 |
+---------+----+--------------+----------------+
```

Is it normal? Should I specify the directory where files needs to be added?

EDIT 2:

My Media Entity:

```
<?php

namespace AdminBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * Media
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="Media", indexes={@ORM\Index(name="fk_Media_Cat_Media1_idx", columns={"Cat_Media_ID"})})
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Media
{
    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="Libelle", type="string", length=45, nullable=true)
     */
    private $libelle;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="ID", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var \AdminBundle\Entity\CatMedia
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AdminBundle\Entity\CatMedia")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="Cat_Media_ID", referencedColumnName="ID")
     * })
     */
    private $catMedia;


    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     *
     *
     * @Assert\File(mimeTypes={ "application/image" })
     */
    private $file;



    /**
     * Set libelle
     *
     * @param string $libelle
     * @return Media
     */
    public function setLibelle($libelle)
    {
        $this->libelle = $libelle;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get libelle
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getLibelle()
    {
        return $this->libelle;
    }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set catMedia
     *
     * @param \AdminBundle\Entity\CatMedia $catMedia
     * @return Media
     */
    public function setCatMedia(\AdminBundle\Entity\CatMedia $catMedia = null)
    {
        $this->catMedia = $catMedia;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get catMedia
     *
     * @return \AdminBundle\Entity\CatMedia 
     */
    public function getCatMedia()
    {
        return $this->catMedia;
    }



    public function setFile($file)
    {
        $this->file = $file;

        return $this;
    }


    public function getFile()
    {
        return $this->file;
    }


}
```

My Media NewAction Controller:

```
/**
     * Creates a new Media entity.
     *
     * @Route("/new", name="media_new")
     * @Method({"GET", "POST"})
     */
    public function newAction(Request $request)
    {
        $media = new Media();
        $form = $this->createForm('AdminBundle\Form\MediaType', $media);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {

                // $file stores the uploaded file
                /** @var Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile $file */
                $file = $media->getFile();

                // Generate a unique name for the file before saving it
                $fileName = md5(uniqid()).'.'.$file->guessExtension();

                // Move the file to the directory where media are stored
                $fileDir = $this->container->getParameter('kernel.root_dir').'/../web/uploads/';
                $file->move($fileDir, $fileName);

                // Update the 'media' property to store the file name
                // instead of its contents
                $media->setFile($fileName);



            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->persist($media);
            $em->flush();

            return $this->redirectToRoute('media_show', array('id' => $media->getId()));
        }

        return $this->render('AdminBundle:media:new.html.twig', array(
            'medium' => $media,
            'form' => $form->createView(),
        ));
    }
```

My media FormType:

```
<?php

namespace AdminBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\FileType;

class MediaType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('libelle')
            ->add('catmedia','entity',  array('class'=>'AdminBundle:CatMedia',
                'property'=>'libelle'))
            ->add('file', FileType::class, array('label' => 'Image (Png or jpg file)'))
        ;
    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolver $resolver
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'AdminBundle\Entity\Media'
        ));
    }


}
```

and User Formtype using Media FormType:

```
<?php

namespace AdminBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class UtilisateurType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('nom')
            ->add('prenom')
            ->add('societe')
            ->add('mail')
            ->add('tel')
            ->add('password')
            ->add('catutilisateur','entity',  array('class'=>'AdminBundle:CatUtilisateur',
                'property'=>'libelle'))
            ->add('media', MediaType::class)



        ;
    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolver $resolver
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'AdminBundle\Entity\Utilisateur'
        ));
    }
}
```

As you can see, i have my move Function. But I do not have the directory uploads into web/, and in the database , I have this famous

> ```
> +---------+----+--------------+----------------+
> | Libelle | ID | Cat_Media_ID | file           |
> +---------+----+--------------+----------------+
> | test    |  1 |            1 | /tmp/phpY0oLd6 |
> +---------+----+--------------+----------------+
> ```

Comment: It's just uploaded file by user, you should move that file to some directory after user finish uploading.

Comment: @malcolm  but is not that what I already do in my newAction ? $fileDir = $this->container->getParameter('kernel.root_dir').'/../web/uploads/';
                $file->move($fileDir, $fileName);

Comment: How look `Media` entity `setFile()` method?

Comment: @malcolm i edited my post with setFile() function

Comment: It's impossible that `md5(uniqid()).'.'.$file->guessExtension();` return `/tmp/phpY0oLd6` , you paste wrong code or something there that you missing. Is there any functions in your media entity that modify `$file` property?

Comment: @malcom nope. I edited my post again. I added all entity, controller, and formType content.

Comment: I don't help you with this. All code you paste show that it should save md5 string plus file extension to database. Maybe you have a listener that modify file property, really don't know without see the whole code.

Answer (score 1):

After upload move the file to your desired directory and you will get a `File` object in return.

```
$file = $uploadedFile->move($directory, $name);
```

In Symfony applications, uploaded files are objects of the UploadedFile class, which provides methods for the most common operations when dealing with uploaded files;

[See Symfony Api](http://api.symfony.com/2.8/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/File/UploadedFile.html#method_move)

Comment: I have perhaps not been specific enough in my post . I edited it with the controller. As you can see, i have a move function. 
but it is not working. Thx for your help :)

Comment: No errors, nothing. only some deprecated warnings. phpStorm say "FILE" namespace is undefined

Comment: You are probably doing a flush on `$media->setFile($fileName);` as malcolm asked can you post it here

Comment: done. in don't understood what is wrong with this function !